# Creating input text field on marked checkbox in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I was asked to do something particular, and after trying I eventually found this site https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri from which I'm using the JQuery. I however don't have any knowledge of it so I only understand in parts. What I'm trying to do is upon marking a checkbox an `input type="text"` appears below it, so if I check 3 results, `input type="text"`creates 3 fields, etc, and if I uncheck a checkbox, the camp gets deleted.

I've tried to do it by adding

```
$("div bb")
{
$('<input type="text" id="textbox" style="width:170px;"/><span> CHF <span>');
            }
```

after `$(".hida").hide();`but as I have no knowledge of JQuery it obviously didn't work and I don't really know what now. Also before that input, is it possible to add some sort of variable that  is "attached" to the input so I can specificy what that input is for? Like if I check "Mercedes"  in the checkbox, the `input type="text"` is created and above it the name "Mercedes" then if I check "BMW" it makes another `input type="text"` with BMW written above it?

Also wruting the code like this `$("div bb") {` for some reason disabled the $. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

1. create an empty element in your html where the input fields
   should appear (e.g. `<div id="textfields"></div>`)
2. find the "on-checkbox-click-event-handler", which happens to be this line in the jquery: `$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {`
3. add code to the handler at the correct location, to append/delete a text box (difficult if you don't know jquery at all). The correct location is where jquery looks for the "checked-state" of the checkbox. Use `$().append()` to create the text field and `$().remove()` to remove on unchecking the checkbox. Should be something like `$("#textfields").append("<input type='text'/>");` you will need to add a class to the input field to later address it when removing.

Working pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRdmXj

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, it's almost exactly what I wanted! I think I can figure out the smaller details to make it what I was thinking, but thank you a lot. Was stuck for 2 days at this.

Comment: It's hard at the beginning. But get's much easier when you understand the jquery concept. Greetings to Lugano and keep it up!